# Cannot remove installed Nuget package for solution in MSVS 2019

Tags: package, nuget, visual-studio-2019, uninstallation

In Visual Studio 2019, with Nuget package manager at the solution level, I can't remove an installed package  because the Uninstall button is greyed out.
The Nuget solution has the package checked as installed for one or more projects, but those projects do not have the package referenced in their References.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the packages button that selects all the packages as if you want to install the package on all projects in the solution.  The uninstall button can now be clicked and it will uninstall the package everywhere.